# include файла php для обработчика задач Cron

Tags: php, cron, include

Возникла проблема с обработчиком Cron, а если точнее то проблема с подключением файла через include в скрипте который запускает Cron.

Теперь по порядку

Код скрипта для Cron:

```
<?php
include_once 'setting.php';
$CONNECT = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "DELETE FROM `statistics` WHERE `last_visit` < SUBTIME(NOW(), '180 0:00:0')");
?>
```

Сам файл с этим скриптом лежит в папке, а файл setting.php - в корне сайта на один уровень выше, и поэтому Cron выдает ошибку:

> Warning: include(setting.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home3/bdsfpowl/public_html/automation/online.php on line
>   2
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'setting.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home3/bdsfpowl/public_html/automation/online.php on line 2

Помогите разобраться как корректно подключить setting.php для скрипта, потому что если скрипт переместить в корень сайта то все работает нормально.

Answer (score 2):

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/setting.php';
```

Comment: Добавьте комментарии описанного действия, иначе ответ может быть удален модератором.

Comment: _DIR_ возвращает директорию файла с которого выполняется, то есть в этом случае он вернет директорию скрипта и будет искать setting.php в той папке где и файл скрипта, а надо чтобы искал в корне сайта

Comment: `..` — жёсткая ссылка на родительский каталог.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему просто прописав полный путь к файлу начиная от корня хостинга

```
include_once '/home/bdsfpowl/public_html/setting.php';
```